# SQL to Insert a file.exe in Postgres

Tags: sql, file

How coul'd  i, insert a file.exe in postgres using a SQL???

my table
CREATE TABLE versaoatualizada (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nome character varying,
    arquivo Oid,
    CONSTRAINT pk_arquivo PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_arquivo INCREMENT 1 START 1;

my jAVA CODE

but i found some problems...
i have  an exeption (Cast bigInteger to Oid..)

```
public File getFile(int id) {
        File f = null;
        try {
            List<Object[]> lista = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("sqlWorking").getResultList();
            Oid bytes;
            Object[] a = lista.get(0);
            bytes = (Oid) a[2];// oid field
            f = new File("C:.......");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(bytes.getDER());
            fos.close();
            return f;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `arquivo` column should have a type of `oid`, per the [function documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/lo-interfaces.html#LO-IMPORT).